# Why I get 500 internal server error when using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I am keep getting a 500 internal server error when accessing the folder.

It does come up with a dialog asking to enter username and password.

But once entered 500 internal server error

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /customers/7/f/d/reedyfordmobilevaletservice.co.uk//httpd.www/admin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log file and see what the error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change your rule to this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!public/)` is negative lookahead to prevent looping.